# Що означає суфікс "-енко" в українських прізвищах і звідки він прийшов

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Багацько прізвищ у нас закінчуються на "-енко". На [Вікіпедії пишуть](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_-%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE), що таких 60% з українських прізвищ. Також пишуть, що *син людини з прізвищем Коваль міг отримати прізвище Коваленко (син Коваля).* Цікаво чому "-енко" це означає, звідки воно прийшло?

Comment: Українська Вікіпедія містить розлогу статтю [Українські прізвища](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0#.D0.86.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D0.B2.D1.96.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96) на цю тему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Українська мова: Енциклопедія](http://1576.ua/books/4995) на сторінці 533 пише, що суфікс **-енко** разом з кількома иншими (**-юк, -чук, -як, -чак, -ик, -чик, -ко, -ка, -ок, -онок, -еня, -я, -ча, -чо, -ець, -цьо, -ина**) початково був *демінутивним*, зменшувальним, отже колись слово *коваленко* означало «маленький коваль», потім «син коваля», «син Коваля», а потім перетворилося на родове ім’я, прізвище родини, яку започаткував коваль на прізвисько Коваль.