# Яка етимологія прізвищ із суфіксами та імен по батькові в українській мові?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Що в оригіналі означали суфікси в українських прізвищах -енко (Федоренко), -ко (Федірко), -ук/юк (Федорук), -чук (Федорчук). Чи є якась різниця в семантиці цих суфіксів?

Також, що значили слова на -ва (Федорова), -вна (Федорівна) (для жіночого роду) і -ич (Федорович), -ів (Федорів) (для чоловічого)? Чи бували такі форми похідними тільки від імен (Федір — Федорович), чи також і від прізвищ (Федорчук — Федорчукович)?

Comment: Частково це питання вже обговорено тут http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/343/36

Comment: Чи не варто це розбити на два окремі питання: одне — про те, чи була якась різниця в семантиці -енко, -ко, -ук/юк, -чук (здається, саме походження їх, як зменшувальних, [вже встановили](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/344/4)), а друге — чи бували -ва, -вна, -ич, -ів похідними не від імен, а від інших прізвищ? Якщо я правильно Вас зрозумів, і нічого не пропустив. Чи це якимсь чином пов'язані два питання?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. -енко (Федоренко), -ко (Федірко), -ук/юк (Федорук), -чук (Федорчук)**

Дублюю [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/344/240) користувача Yellow Sky на ідентичне питання:

> [Українська мова: Енциклопедія](http://1576.ua/books/4995) на сторінці 533 пише, що суфікс -енко разом з кількома иншими (-юк, -чук, -як, -чак, -ик, -чик, -ко, -ка, -ок, -онок, -еня, -я, -ча, -чо, -ець, -цьо, -ина) початково був демінутивним, зменшувальним, отже колись слово коваленко означало «маленький коваль», потім «син коваля», «син Коваля», а потім перетворилося на родове ім’я, прізвище родини, яку започаткував коваль на прізвисько Коваль.

**2. -ва (Федорова), -вна (Федорівна) і -ич (Федорович), -ів (Федорів)**

Посилатимусь на книгу "[Сучасні Українські Прізвища](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshron.chtyvo.org.ua%2FRedko_Yulian%2FSuchasni_ukrainski_prizvyscha.pdf)" Юліана Редько.

Сторінка 17:

> Прізвища з суфіксами **-ич, -анич, -евич, -ович**. За походженням це дуже давні утворення, відомі, головним чином, у східних і південних слов'ян з найдавніших часів. Суфікси ці служили для утворення назви сина від імені батька чи матері.

Сторінка 19:

> Прізвища на **-ів, -ин, -ишин** вказували на ім'я батька або матері. Первісно вони відмінювалися як присвійні прикметники, а в багатьох західних говірках досі
>   зберегли прикметникове відмінювання.

Тут невпевнений, чи можна цим пояснити -ова, але, здається, аналоґія хороша:

> У непрямих відмінках звук **і** в суфіксі чергується з **о**: Адамова, Гаврилова.

Про -вна, нажаль, нічого не знаходжу.

Comment: Дякую. Ще би про -вна дізнатися :) І про `Чи бували такі форми похідними тільки від імен (Федір — Федорович), чи також і від прізвищ (Федорчук — Федорчукович)?`

Comment: @Maksym тут я не можу підкріпити джерелами, але зазначу таке: зазвичай такі складні прізвища на кшталт "Федорчукович" - це просто нагромадження, яке відбувається через бажання когось виглядати поважніше. Типу, "-он, які ці -овичи солідні, зроблю й собі таке прізвище". Як буде нагода - ще пошукаю.