# Як правильно зробити переклад "Иван Царевич и Серый Волк"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

***Як правильно зробити переклад назви мультфільму "Иван Царевич и Серый Волк"?***

На телеканалі "Новий канал" в анонсі показали відео на даний мультфільм із назвою ***"Іван Княженко і Сірий Вовк"***, на цьому [сайті](https://tvbesedka.com.ua/channel/nkua/2018/03/31) зазначена така ж назва.

Як утворився саме такий переклад для мене не зрозуміло. На мою думку, більш логічним був би переклад ***"Іван Царевич і Сірий Вовк".***

Адже в СУМ-11 присутне визначення саме

> **[ЦАРЕВИЧ](http://sum.in.ua/s/carevych)** а, чоловічий рід. Син царя (у 1 знач.).

також є

> **[КНЯЗЕНКО](http://sum.in.ua/s/knjazenko)** Молодий син князя (у 1, 2 знач.).

Визначення слово **"княженко"** не знайшла, можливо воно утворилося від ["княжити"](http://sum.in.ua/s/knjazhyty) (правити князівством)?!

Чи можна вважати ***"Іван Княженко і Сірий Вовк"***  нормативним перекладом?

Answer (score 4):

В ["Етимологічному словнику"т.2](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо:

> князь, княгиня,княгівна, [князівна], княгиня, княжа,[княжевич] Ж княженецтво,"гідність князя", **[**княженко**]

В [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/knjazhych):

> **КНЯ́ЖИЧ,** а, чол., іст. Те саме, що **князенко**. Боярин Мирослав узяв на руки княжича Данила і, держачи поперед себе, гукнув: — Ось князь наш! (Антон Хижняк, Д. Галицький, 1958, 26); Сам король частує знатних гостей — королевичів та княжичів (Анатолій Шиян, Іван — мужицький син, 1959, 20).

А, оскільки, [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/knjazenko)

> КНЯЗЕ́НКО, а, чол., іст. Молодий син князя,

то
[Княжити](http://sum.in.ua/s/knjazhyty) + енк (суфікс пестливості) [Офіційний сайт української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/ukrajinskij_pravopis_2007/pravopis_osnovi_slova/pravopis_sufiksiv_imennikovi_sufiksi/12-1-0-311) = княженко( також молодий син князя)

Отже, такий переклад є нормативним.

Answer (score 1):

Перекладачі відповідально підійшли до справи, хоча результат, м'яко кажучи, кумедний. В добу Київської Русі не могло бути жодних царів, а всі, хто був, носив українські прізвища. Навіть у російських казках. Тільки цим можна пояснити перетворення сина царя на княжича. Щодо ж суфікса -енко, маємо [таку інформацію](https://uamodna.com/articles/chomu-bagato-ukrayinsjkyh-prizvysch-zakinchuyutjsya-na-enko/):

> Дослідник Степан Бевзенко, який вивчав реєстр Київського полку
>   середини XVII століття, зазначає, що прізвища, які закінчуються на
>   "енко" становили приблизно 60% від усього списку фамільних імен полку.
>   Суфікс "енко" – зменшувальний і підкреслює зв’язок з батьком, що
>   буквально означало "маленький", "молода людина", "син". Наприклад,
>   Петренко – син Петра або Ющенко – син Юська.   Пізніше древній суфікс
>   втратив своє пряме значення і почав використовуватися як фамільний
>   компонент. Зокрема він став доповненням не тільки для патронімів, але
>   й для прізвиськ і професій – Зубченко, Мельниченко.

Подібне обговорення також є [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/343/%D0%A9%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%94-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%96-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Не дуже зрозуміло, яким чином цей допис відповідає на запитання. Більше схоже на (розлогий) коментар.